# Find row value in CSV from column header and PSMember Properties

Tags: powershell, csv

I am writing a program that will remove rows with bad values. The column names are not known beforehand, so it's important that they are not hardcoded. I  am trying to read a CSV file using the column header as an index for the data structure. I store the CSVs properties using the `MemberType` property. This lets me get the name but not the value!

Here is my code:

```
$data = .\hash_file.ps1
$csv = Import-Csv .\ps_test.csv

$properties = $csv | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ | Get-Member -MemberType Property, NoteProperty
}

foreach ($property in $properties) {
    "here is the column name: " + $property.Name
    "Here is the set of all values in [column, row]: " + $csv[$property.Name] #this does not return 
    foreach ($key in $data.Keys) {
        "Here is the set of all values to purge: " + $data[$key]
        if ($property.Name -eq $key -And $data[$key] -contains $property.Value){
            "Here is the purged property: " + $property.Value
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my results:

```
here is the column name: car
Here is the set of all values in [column, row]:#???
Here is the set of all values to purge: robert
Here is the set of all values to purge: nissan exterra
here is the column name: name
Here is the set of all values in [column, row]:#???
Here is the set of all values to purge: robert
Here is the set of all values to purge: nissan exterra
here is the column name: car
Here is the set of all values in [column, row]:#???
Here is the set of all values to purge: robert
Here is the set of all values to purge: nissan exterra
here is the column name: name
Here is the set of all values in [column, row]:#???
Here is the set of all values to purge: robert
Here is the set of all values to purge: nissan exterra
```

My data is stored in a CSV like this:

```
#ps_test.csv
name    car
----    -------
clay    nissan exterra
casey   honda accord
henry   nissan exterra
robert  truck
```

The items to purge are stored as column, value pairs in the hashtable:

```
#hash_file.ps1
@{
    "name" = @("robert");
    "car"  = @("nissan exterra")
}
```

Here is an example result:

```
Here is the column name: name
Here is the set of all values in [column, row]:#???
Here is the set of all values to purge: robert
Here is the set of all values to purge: nissan exterra
```

It ought to read "name", "clay","robert","nissan exterra". But I can't get "clay".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I kind of like where you're going with this and how flexible it is, but you are trying to iterate through rows, and validate properties of that row, and instead your script is iterating through all properties of all rows. Let's restructure a little bit.

You start out strong by loading up your hashtable and csv, we'll keep that:

```
$data = .\hash_file.ps1
$csv = import-csv .\ps_test.csv
```

But then things start to go sideways. What you want to do is iterate each row, so let's go there first:

```
ForEach($Row in $CSV){
```

Ok, now for that row, which is actually a `[PSCustomObject]` once it's imported, you can get your properties of that object (aka the column names) by referencing the PSObject hidden property. So let's do that:

```
$Row.PSObject.Properties.Name
```

Neat, that tells us what all properties we're dealing with. Then we can just look at each property in a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
$Row.PSObject.Properties.Name | ForEach{
    "Column Name: $_"
    "Row value for $_`: " + $Row.$_
    "Values to purge for $_`: " + $Data[$_] -join ', '
    If($Row.$_ -in $Data[$_]){
        "Record purged: " + $Row
    }
}
```

So let's put that all together:

```
$data = .\hash_file.ps1
$csv = import-csv .\ps_test.csv
ForEach($Row in $CSV){
    $Row.PSObject.Properties.Name | ForEach{
        "Column Name: $_"
        "Row value for $_`: " + $Row.$_
        "Values to purge for $_`: " + $Data[$_] -join ', '
        If($Row.$_ -in $Data[$_]){
            "Record purged: " + $Row
        }
    }
}
```

That results in what I'm pretty sure you want:

```
Column Name: Name
Row value for Name: clay
Values to purge for Name: robert
Column Name: Car
Row value for Car: nissan exterra
Values to purge for Car: nissan exterra
Record purged: @{Name=clay; Car=nissan exterra}
Column Name: Name
Row value for Name: casey
Values to purge for Name: robert
Column Name: Car
Row value for Car: honda accord
Values to purge for Car: nissan exterra
Column Name: Name
Row value for Name: henry
Values to purge for Name: robert
Column Name: Car
Row value for Car: nissan exterra
Values to purge for Car: nissan exterra
Record purged: @{Name=henry; Car=nissan exterra}
Column Name: Name
Row value for Name: robert
Values to purge for Name: robert
Record purged: @{Name=robert; Car=truck}
Column Name: Car
Row value for Car: truck
Values to purge for Car: nissan exterra
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I liked the uplifting commentary. :)

Comment: $row.psobject.properties.name is returning as null.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? Pretty sure that should work on anything v3 or higher. Unless `$Row` is null.

Comment: It's v.2. Is the psobject syntax different for older versions?

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate data of csv dynamically with this other method:

```
$data=@{
    name = [string[]]("robert");
    car  = [string[]]("nissan exterra", "toyota")
}

import-csv "c:\temp\ps_test.csv"  | %{
foreach ($key in $data.Keys)
{
   foreach ($value in $data[$key])
   {
      if ($_."$key" -EQ $value)
      {
          #you can purge here
          #$_."$key"=$null
      } 
   }
}

$_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only get part of what you are trying to do, but I hope this helps:

```
#step.ps1  -- steps through a csv file looking at each value

$data = .\hash-file.ps1
$csv = Import-Csv .\ps-test.csv

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    foreach ($column in $row.psobject.properties) {
        "Here is the column name: " + $column.name
        "Here is the current value: " + $column.value
        "Here is the set of all values to purge: " + $data[$column.name]
    }
}
```

Here's what I used for hash-file:

```
#hash-file.ps1

@{
    "name" = @("robert");
    "car" = @("nissan exterra")
}
```

And here's what I used for the csv file:

```
#ps-test.csv
name,car
clay,nissan exterra
casey,honda accord
henry,nissan exterra
robert, truck
```

Note that I used hyphen instead of underscore.
Note that a csv file can have comments in it.

As I said, this is only part of the way, but I hope it helps.